# With the same site number, is it possible to list the current value and that of two hours ago all together?

Tags: sql-server

I have time-series data for a number of gauging stations and developed methodology, described below to determine whether river level is rising, steady or falling.

**Method:**
grab the oldest value within a time frame such as two hours and compares that value with the latest using the tolerance method of within a tolerance range of each, such as 0.5 cm then the site is 'steady'. If the latest value is above the tolerance then the tendency is 'rising' and if below then it is 'falling'.

How do I transfer the methodology into `#T-SQL?`

The date set format is like Site, Value and DT

```
Site     Value       DT
12345678    0   13/01/2019 0:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 1:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 2:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 3:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 4:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 5:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 6:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 7:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 8:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 9:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 10:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 11:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 13:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 14:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 16:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 17:00
12345678   0.05 13/01/2019 17:57     
12345678   0.15 13/01/2019 17:57     
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 17:58     
12345678   0.25 13/01/2019 17:58     
12345678   0.30 13/01/2019 17:59     
12345678   0.35 13/01/2019 17:59     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 18:00            
12345678   0.50 13/01/2019 18:01     
12345678   0.55 13/01/2019 18:03     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 19:00     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 20:00     
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 21:00     
12345678   0.10 13/01/2019 22:00          
12345678    0   13/01/2019 23:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 0:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 1:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 2:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 3:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 4:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 5:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 6:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 7:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 8:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 9:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 10:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 11:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 12:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 13:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 14:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 15:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 16:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 17:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 18:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 19:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 20:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 21:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 22:00
```

I have tried to use `DATEADD` and `BETWEEN` to find the oldest value within two hours without success.

Here is an expected output data set (manually generated). The reason why the tendency at 13/01/2019 17:57 is rising is because firstly it compares the oldest value within a time frame of two hours, which is 13/01/2019 16:00 and the value of 0, with itself(0.5) and also the it exceeds the tolerance of 0.5 (0.5-0=0.5) This two factors contributes the result of tendency as Rising. On 13/01/2019 20:00, the value reached 0.40 which is the same as two hours ago (18:00) and less than the difference of 0.5, resulting in Steady. On 13/01/2019 21:00, the tendency is falling because of the comparison between that and the value at 19:00 (0.4) plus the difference is more than 0.5.

```
Site     Value       DT              Tendency
12345678    0   13/01/2019 0:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 1:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 2:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 3:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 4:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 5:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 6:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 7:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 8:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 9:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 10:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 11:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 13:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 14:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 16:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 17:00     Steady
12345678   0.05 13/01/2019 17:57     Rising
12345678   0.15 13/01/2019 17:57     Rising
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 17:58     Rising
12345678   0.25 13/01/2019 17:58     Rising
12345678   0.30 13/01/2019 17:59     Rising
12345678   0.35 13/01/2019 17:59     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 18:00     Rising
12345678   0.50 13/01/2019 18:01     Rising
12345678   0.55 13/01/2019 18:03     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 19:00     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 20:00     Steady
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 21:00     Falling
12345678   0.10 13/01/2019 22:00     Falling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome YuChun!

I used a CTE which joins the table of data to itself in order to identify the matching rows of data which represents the LAST row of data at least 120 minutes older:

```
DECLARE @TOLERANCE DECIMAL(10,4) = 0.05
;WITH cte ( siteid, dt, lvl, priordt, priorlvl, priorrownum ) as (
SELECT c.siteid,
       c.dt,
       c.lvl,
       priordt = p.dt,
       p.lvl,
       row_number()
           OVER (
               partition BY c.siteid, c.dt
               ORDER BY p.dt DESC)
  FROM @data c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @data p ON c.siteid = p.siteid
                              AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.dt, c.dt) >= 120 
)
SELECT cte.siteid,
       cte.lvl,
       cte.dt,
       CASE
         WHEN ABS(cte.lvl - cte.priorlvl) >= @TOLERANCE
              AND cte.lvl > cte.priorlvl THEN N'Rising'
         WHEN ABS(cte.lvl - cte.priorlvl) >= @TOLERANCE
              AND cte.lvl < cte.priorlvl THEN N'Falling'
         ELSE N'Steady'
       END,
       cte.priorlvl
  FROM cte
 WHERE priorrownum = 1
```

The `CASE` statement checks for differences greater than or equal to the `@TOLERANCE` value and then whether the new value is increasing or decreasing.

Hope this helps get you started in the right direction.

NOTE: I used the `MINUTE` interval in `DATEDIFF` because the `HOUR` value was too imprecise (it assumes 18:03 is two hours before 20:00).

Comment: Thank you! it works really good. However, I have around 1 million sets of value and  "row_number() OVER "  statement took more than 1 hour to run each time. do you have a way to work around? potentially take less time to run?

Comment: Without a dataset of that volume to play with, I would be guessing (and not well, I would think). Out of curiosity, how fast is the select inside the CTE if you change it from a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`? I know it will give incorrect results (site/dt combinations without a corresponding entry 2hrs prior will be dropped). But I am curious to know if it comes back much faster.